# Connect to server to remotely access a Linux computer via GUI

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote

I'm working from home on my laptop which runs on **Ubuntu** and I would like to access my work computer which runs on **Mageia**. Usually I just gain access through terminal like this: `ssh -p <port> -X <account>@<IP address>`. This works well but for convenience I want to be able to use GUI (i.e., click on folders to open and manipulate files. Previously when I used Centos, it's pretty easy: provide the IP address, home folder, account, and password. With Ubuntu, I'm not sure how to do so. I've tried using `File --> Connect Server` then tried various ways of inputting server address (per my research from Ubuntu website) but nothing worked. Perhaps my server address wasn't in the correct format. Could anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with GUI? If you're connecting with `-X` option, you have X11 forwarding enabled, which means any command that you run from on the remote box will output its GUI on your screen. I don't think I see what else you'd want to do.

Comment: I want to access a large number of images. Accessing them through terminal and opening them doesn't seem to be all that convenient.

Comment: Agreed. Why not run `nemo`, `dolphin`, `thunar`, `nautilus` or whatever file manager you use on Mageia? With X11 you should be able to run a file manager from terminal and just click your way through.

Comment: GUI would eat up all your bandwidth. If I were you, I'd prefer terminal for linux but since you're an office guy...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Remmina Remote Desktop** on **Ubuntu** to connect to the **Mageia** running work computer.

To do this in Gnome, *Panel*>*Applications*>*Internet*>*Remmina Remote Desktop*